# CPC1002N - Using as Relay

Tags: mosfet

After a research on MOSFET use, I've found that I'm unable to connect load on Source in N-type without additional consideration.

About this component CPC1002N http://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/CPC1002N.pdf/$file/CPC1002N.pdf

I've a MOSFET driven by a LED, N-Type. This component is described as Relay, in this case should I take in consideration that load still need be on Drain becouse there's MOSFET inside?
Or can I put load where I prefer since Vgs is given by an optocoupler?

Answer (score 0):

A mosfet (so, also in the solid state relay) has a substrate diode that conducts when the source potential is higher than the drain potential. So, care should be taken how to connect the "load".

When you have a SSR made off two mosfets arranged back-to-back with their source pins tied together, their substrate diode are anti-series and it will not matter how the "load" is applied.

[image]

Comment: So, as I understood, doesn't matter if in CPC1002N I have a diode as gate or there's relay written on datasheets. It acts like a normal MOSFET with optoisolated activation.